# Endnotes section divided into subsections (follow-up)

Tags: titlesec, endnotes

This is a follow up from the question discussed here: [Endnotes section divided into subsections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/699698/endnotes-section-divided-into-subsections)

My original code being turned into a MWE as much as possible is (below). My document has an unnumbered 'PREFACE' section and a number of numbered sections (chapters). Each of these sections have footnotes. The latter must be placed at the very end of the document under 'ENDNOTES' title and grouped by respective section titles.

The issue is that my extended MWE code (see pics below) does not produce a desired look (the one that was obtained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/699698/endnotes-section-divided-into-subsections)). It must be, I suspect, due to my manipulations with sections rules (there is a section, in preamble, for that in my extended MWE code):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Set the page margins as required
\usepackage[left=1.25in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}         
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing   
\expandafter\def\expandafter\quote     
   \expandafter{\quote\small\singlespacing}

%--- Acronyms
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{fbb}{
  short=FBB,
  long=foo bar baz,
}

%--- Endnotes
% Adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109566/105447
\usepackage{endnotes}

% Reset endnote numbering every section
\counterwithin*{endnote}{section}

\makeatletter
\NewCommandCopy\latexsection\section
\renewcommand\enoteheading{%
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
\latexsection*{\notesname}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}} % adjust to suit
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\MakeUppercase{\notesname}}
\let\@afterindentfalse\@afterindenttrue
}
\makeatother
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{som}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}
  {\latexsection*{#3}%
   \setcounter{endnote}{0}%
   \addtoendnotes{%
   \noexpand\enotedivision{\noexpand\subsubsection*}
  {\unexpanded{#3}}}%
}
{\IfNoValueTF{#2}
  {\latexsection{#3}}
  {\latexsection[#2]{#3}}%
  \addtoendnotes{%
   \noexpand\enotedivision{\noexpand\subsubsection*}
   {\thesection. \unexpanded{#3}}}%
}%
}
\makeatletter
\def\enotedivision#1#2{\@ifnextchar\enotedivision{}{#1{#2}}}
\makeatletter
\let\footnote=\endnote
%--- ...end of Endnotes

%--- Sections
% Managing sections
\usepackage{titlesec}     % To modify the section titles
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}} % CHAPTER 1 [New Line] TITLE
\titleformat{\section}[display]            % each chapter has two lines...
  {\normalfont\Large\filcenter}{\MakeUppercase{Chapter~\thesection}}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{24pt}    % {0pt}{*0}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{12pt}{6pt} % 24pt before, 6pt after subsection
% Capitalizing the titles of the respective sections:
\renewcommand{\notesname}{\centering \MakeUppercase{Endnotes}}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centering \MakeUppercase{Contents}}
\renewcommand{\refname}{\centering \MakeUppercase{References}}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\centering \MakeUppercase{List of Illustrations}}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\centering \MakeUppercase{List of Tables}}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}      % <-- ...to modify ToC, LoF, and LoT
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{4}      % dots spacing
\renewcommand{\cftsecdotsep}{4}   % dots spacing for sections 
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecdotsep}{4}% dots spacing for subsections
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Large} % ToC = Table of Contents
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\Large} % LoF = List of Figures
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hfill\Large} % LoT = List of Tables
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hfill}
%--- ...end of Sections

% ----- Start of the document --------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

{\let\bfseries\mdseries \tableofcontents}
\newpage

\printacronyms[name=\MakeUppercase{List of Acronyms}]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\MakeUppercase{List of Acronyms}}

\section*{\MakeUppercase{Preface}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\MakeUppercase{Preface}}
\lipsum[1-4]\footnote{foo bar baz in Preface}\ac{fbb}
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{\MakeUppercase{Intro \& Plan}}
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]\footnote{foo bar baz in Ch1}\ac{fbb}

\newpage

\section{\MakeUppercase{Literature Review}}
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]\footnote{foo bar baz in Ch2}\ac{fbb}

\newpage

\addtoendnotes{\unexpanded{\enotedivision{}{}}}
\theendnotes

\end{document}
% ----- End of the document ----------------------------------------------------
```

[image: Output file look]

Comment: What's the question exactly? What are you trying to change in the output?

Comment: Did you try the suggestion you received in comments on the earlier answer you got? That is, move the notes stuff after the `titlesec` stuff. If you did, please explain why that didn't work.

Comment: @cfr I am to write the answer in this thread. Moving the `endnotes` rules after the 'titlesec' did work for me.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my question is in the following code (below). It produces the desired output with ENDNOTES section being organized under respective unnumbered/numbered sections (see screenshot at the bottom).

At its core, the issue was **ordering** of things in the preamble of the LaTeX file. It turned out that (a) package `titlesec` redefines `\section` and (b) our customization of `endnotes` to have split sections of the notes also requires a redefinition of `\section`. Thus, if (b) is placed ahead of (a) then the loading of `titlesec` would overwrite our redefinition. However, placing (b) after (a), ensuring our redefinition of `\section` is done after `titlesec` is loaded, produced the desired look of the ENDNOTES section.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Set the page margins as required
\usepackage[left=1.25in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}         
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing   
\expandafter\def\expandafter\quote     
  \expandafter{\quote\small\singlespacing}

%--- Acronyms
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{fbb}{
  short=FBB,
  long=foo bar baz,
}
\DeclareAcronym{zbb}{
  short=ZBB,
  long=zoo bar baz,
}

%--- ... end of Acronyms

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=2, title={INDEX}]

%--- Sections
% Managing sections
\usepackage{titlesec}     % To modify the section titles
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}} % CHAPTER 1 [New Line] TITLE
\titleformat{\section}[display]            % each chapter has two lines...
  {\normalfont\Large\filcenter}{\MakeUppercase{Chapter~\thesection}}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{24pt}    % {0pt}{*0}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{12pt}{6pt} % 24pt before, 6pt after subsection
% Capitalizing the titles of the respective sections:
\renewcommand{\notesname}{\centering \MakeUppercase{Endnotes}}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centering \MakeUppercase{Contents}}
\renewcommand{\refname}{\centering \MakeUppercase{References}}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\centering \MakeUppercase{List of Illustrations}}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\centering \MakeUppercase{List of Tables}}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}      % <-- ...to modify ToC, LoF, and LoT
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{4}      % dots spacing
\renewcommand{\cftsecdotsep}{4}   % dots spacing for sections 
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecdotsep}{4}% dots spacing for subsections
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Large} % ToC = Table of Contents
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\Large} % LoF = List of Figures
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hfill\Large} % LoT = List of Tables
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hfill}
%--- ...end of Sections

%--- Endnotes
% Adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109566/105447

% Reset endnote numbering every section
\counterwithin*{endnote}{section}

\makeatletter
\NewCommandCopy\latexsection\section
\renewcommand\enoteheading{%
  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
  \latexsection*{\notesname}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}} % adjust to suit
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\MakeUppercase{\notesname}}
  % I don't think this is needed in this case, and you get excessive space
  % with it imho.
  % \mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip
  \let\@afterindentfalse\@afterindenttrue
}
\makeatother

% It's no longer need to load xparse for \RenewDocumentCommand
% \usepackage{xparse}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{som}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
  {\latexsection*{#3}%
    \setcounter{endnote}{0}%
    \addtoendnotes{%
      \noexpand\enotedivision{\noexpand\subsubsection*}
      {\unexpanded{#3}}}%
  }
  {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
    {\latexsection{#3}}
    {\latexsection[#2]{#3}}%
    \addtoendnotes{%
     \noexpand\enotedivision{\noexpand\subsubsection*}
     {\thesection. \unexpanded{#3}}}%
  }%
}
\makeatletter
\def\enotedivision#1#2{\@ifnextchar\enotedivision{}{#1{#2}}}
\makeatletter
\let\footnote=\endnote
%--- ...end of Endnotes

% ----- Start of the document --------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
{\let\bfseries\mdseries \tableofcontents}
\newpage

%\printacronyms[pages={display=all,seq/use=false}, name=\MakeUppercase{List of Acronyms}]
\printacronyms[name=\MakeUppercase{List of Acronyms}]
%\printacronyms
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\MakeUppercase{List of Acronyms}}
\newpage

\section*{\MakeUppercase{Preface}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\MakeUppercase{Preface}}
\lipsum[1-4]\footnote{foo bar baz in Preface}\ac{fbb}
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{\MakeUppercase{Intro \& Plan}}
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]\footnote{foo bar baz in Ch1} And \ac{fbb} with \ac{zbb}...

\newpage

\section{\MakeUppercase{Literature Review}}
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]\footnote{foo bar baz in Ch2} And \ac{fbb} with \ac{zbb}...

\newpage

\addtoendnotes{\unexpanded{\enotedivision{}{}}}
\theendnotes

\end{document}
% ----- End of the document ----------------------------------------------------
```

[image]

Comment: It would be nice if you explained the reason for the problem (namely, redefining `\section` then loading `titlesec`, which overwrote the redefinition) and what you did to fix it. Other than that, +1, thanks.

Comment: @gusbrs please, check my explanation above. Is this okay?

Comment: Alex, I took the liberty of editing a little for clearness. Thanks again.

Comment: @gusbrs thanks!