# Chapter numbers/title in endnotes: spurious titles

Tags: chapters, endnotes

This question relates to some existing entries on formatting endnotes to include chapter headings and numbers.  The relevant entries are:

[Chapter numbers in endnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109559/chapter-name-appearing-in-the-endnotes)

[Chapter name appearing in the endnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109559/chapter-name-appearing-in-the-endnotes)

The problem: the endnotes include the final chapter of the document even if it does not have endnotes in it.  That is, there are many chapters in a document; some have endnotes, some don't.  The very last chapter does **not** have endnotes.  The endnotes, however, always seem to contain the chapter heading for the last chapter.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{endnotes,chngcntr}

\counterwithin*{endnote}{chapter}  % Reset endnote numbering every new chapter

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\enoteheading{%
  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
  \chapter*{\notesname}
  \mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip
  \let\@afterindentfalse\@afterindenttrue
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{xparse}

\let\latexchapter\chapter

\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{som}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\latexchapter*{#3}}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
       {\latexchapter{#3}}
       {\latexchapter[#2]{#3}}%
     \addtoendnotes{%
       \noexpand\enotedivision{\noexpand\subsection}
         {\chaptername\ \thechapter. \unexpanded{#3}}}%
    }%
}
\makeatletter
\def\enotedivision#1#2{\@ifnextchar\enotedivision{}{#1{#2}}}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\chapter{The first chapter}
Here text relating to an endnote.\endnote{This endnote contains some text}
\chapter{The next chapter}
Here is another piece of text that needs an endnote.\endnote{This endnote contains more text}
\chapter{The third chapter}
Here is the last bit of text that needs an endnote.\endnote{This endnote contains a whole lot more text}
\chapter{Fourth chapter}
Stuff here
\chapter{Conclusion}
Some more stuff

\newpage

\begingroup
\def\enotesize{\normalsize}
\theendnotes
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Thanks for any pointers!
[image: Picture of endnotes]

Comment: I think I have solved it but am not sure *why* the solution works.  If you add the line:
    \addtoendnotes{\unexpanded{\enotedivision{}{}}}
Above the call to create the endnotes, it doesn't print the last chapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the problem is actually in the post [Chapter numbers in endnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84914/chapter-numbers-in-endnotes), which is cited in the question.

The solution is to include one line of code (`\addtoendnotes{\unexpanded{\enotedivision{}{}}}`) above `\theendnotes`.

The example above then becomes:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{endnotes,chngcntr}

\counterwithin*{endnote}{chapter}  % Reset endnote numbering every new chapter

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\enoteheading{%
  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
  \chapter*{\notesname}
  \mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip
  \let\@afterindentfalse\@afterindenttrue
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{xparse}

\let\latexchapter\chapter

\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{som}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\latexchapter*{#3}}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
       {\latexchapter{#3}}
       {\latexchapter[#2]{#3}}%
     \addtoendnotes{%
       \noexpand\enotedivision{\noexpand\subsection}
         {\chaptername\ \thechapter. \unexpanded{#3}}}%
    }%
}
\makeatletter
\def\enotedivision#1#2{\@ifnextchar\enotedivision{}{#1{#2}}}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\chapter{The first chapter}
Here text relating to an endnote.\endnote{This endnote contains some text}
\chapter{The next chapter}
Here is another piece of text that needs an endnote.\endnote{This endnote contains more text}
\chapter{The third chapter}
Here is the last bit of text that needs an endnote.\endnote{This endnote contains a whole lot more text}
\chapter{Fourth chapter}
Stuff here
\chapter{Conclusion}
Some more stuff

\newpage

\begingroup
\def\enotesize{\normalsize}
\addtoendnotes{\unexpanded{\enotedivision{}{}}}
\theendnotes
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

This gives the endnotes formatted like this:

[image]