# How to only print endnote section if there are any endnotes?

Tags: conditionals, endnotes, enotez

I am using the `enotez` package and would like to be able to call `\printendnotes` regardless of if there are actually any endnotes. In the case that there are no endnotes I would either like the `\AtEveryEndnotesList` hook to not be evaluated or a way to add content to the hook that would only be used conditionally on there being any endnotes. I would also like to avoid printing the section title in the case of no notes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enotez}
\AtEveryEndnotesList{I do not want to see this}
\begin{document}
\printendnotes
\end{document}
```

Comment: This reads like a feature request…

Comment: @clemens I jut started using the package and really like it. I am happy with a hack for an answerk but am happy to file a feature request also.

Comment: Possible to adapt this answer? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62419/how-to-reset-endnotes-counter-at-parts-and-chapters

Comment: @AubreyBlumsohn I doubt it since all those answers use the endnotes package and I want to use the enotez package.